# Let k, l, m, n be positive real numbers. Prove the following inequality$(kl + lm + km)/(k ^ 3 + l ^ 3 + m ^ 3) ln(kn))/(k ^ 3 + l ^ 3) + (km + mn)$

Tags: inequality

Let k, l, m, n be positive real numbers. Prove the following inequality.

$
\frac{{kl + lm + km}}{{k^3 + l^3 + m^3}} + \frac{{kl + ln + kn)}}{{k^3 + l^3}} + \frac{{km + mn + nk}}{{k^3 + n^3 + m^3}} + lm + nm + ln \leq k^2 + l^2 \left(kl^{\frac{3}{2}} + m^2 + n^2 (mn)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) + k^2 + m^2 (mn)^{\frac{3}{2}} + n^2 (ln)^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{{k^2 + n^2}}{{(kn)^{\frac{3}{2}}}} + \frac{{m^2 + l^2}}{{(lm)^{\frac{3}{2}}}}
$ sorry I am messed up with latex so [image: question]

My attempt

LHS ≥ $[(kl + lm + km)/(kl^2 + kn^2 + km^2)] + [(kl + ln(kn))/(kl^2 + kn^2)] + [(km + mn + nk)/(kn^2 + km^2 + ln^2 + lm^2)] + (lm + nm + ln)$

(ax + by + cz)^2 ≤ (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)

$a = √(kl), b = √(lm), c = √(km)$
$x = √(l^2 + n^2 + m^2), y = √(l^2 + k^2)$
, $z = √(n^2 + k^2)$

$[(kl + lm + km)/(kl^2 + kn^2 + km^2)] = [(√(kl)√(kl) + √(lm)√(lm) + √(km)√(km))/((kl√(l^2 + n^2 + m^2)) + (lm√(l^2 + k^2)) + (km√(n^2 + k^2)))]$

$[(kl + lm + km)/(kl^2 + kn^2 + km^2)] ≤ [(k^2 + l^2 + m^2)(l^2 + k^2 + n^2 + m^2 + n^2 + k^2)] / [(kl^2 + kn^2 + km^2)(l^2 + k^2 + n^2 + m^2 + n^2 + k^2)]$

Comment: Is numerator in second term $kl+kln^2$ or $kl+\ln kn$?

Comment: Sorry that was $kl + ln +kn$